# Strange behaviour of `ReadP` with regards to `fmap head`

Tags: haskell

Consider the following repl session:

```
λ import Text.ParserCombinators.ReadP

λ x $$ y = readP_to_S x y
    -- This auxiliary function makes things tidier.

λ many get $$ "abc"
[("","abc"),("a","bc"),("ab","c"),("abc","")]
    -- This is reasonable.

λ fmap head (many get) $$ "abc"
[(*** Exception: Prelude.head: empty list
    -- Wut?

λ fmap last (many get) $$ "abc"
[(*** Exception: Prelude.last: empty list
    -- This works neither.

λ fmap id (many get) $$ "abc"
[("","abc"),("a","bc"),("ab","c"),("abc","")]
     -- The list is there until I try to chop its head!
```

My questions:

- What is happening here?
- How can I extract a single *(preferably longest)* parse result?

**P.S.** My goal is to construct a parser combinator that greedily returns the repetitive application of a given parser. *(`get` in this instance, but in actuality I have a more involved logic.)* Chopping the list of intermediate results is one approach I thought would do, but I am fine with any, except that it is preferable not to convert to `ReadS` and back.

Comment: Well `$$` has lower priority, so you `fmap head` on `(many get)` not `many get $$ "abc"`. And `fmap id ...` makes no changes at all.

Comment: try `head (many get $$ "abc")` or the equivalent `head $ many get $$ "abc"` to clarify your misunderstanding.

Comment: If you however want the first match, it should be `head (many get $$ "abc")`.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem This does not explain where is that empty list hidden. It does typecheck!

Comment: @IgnatInsarov: well a `ReadP` is the instance of a functor with `fmap h (R f) = R (\k -> f (k . h))`. So you take the head of the first element of the tuples. You can for example query the length of this list, and it will result in `4`. What you thus here are doing is processing the *first* item of every tuple.

Comment: @IgnatInsarov: try for example `fmap ('a':) (many get) $$ "abc"`, it will prepend the elements with `a`.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem Oh, thank you. This is somewhat unexpected. Could you take a look at the postscriptum I just added?

Comment: I think you want `eof`.  Try using `many get <* eof` as your parser and you should only get results that use the whole input.

Comment: @DavidFletcher Yes, I also arrived to this conclusion. Generally, the logically correct way to select one of the range of `many ...` matches is to have some end anchor — for instance, `eof`, rather than ad-hoc list slicing. It must also mean that there is no way to create a "greedy" parser in the usual "regex" sense. Would you like to compose a complete answer so that I may accept it? Including the results of Willem, if possible.